# Set state timeout in react project

Tags: reactjs

I have an e-commerce website that is fetching the backend and filling the state with items' prices.

When I change the prices in the database, how can I force-refresh the frontend, or even set a timeout for the state to force reload after like 1 hour? What is the best practice here?

I don't want the client to have different prices in the frontend and the email he/she receives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have same api and it has no topic on socket, So I call the api every 5 minutes:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
   const getData = async () => {
     const response = await request.get(/* Related api */);

     if (response?.data?.length) {
        setData(response?.data);
      }
   };
   getData();
   const interval = setInterval(() => getData(), 300000);
   return () => {
     clearInterval(interval);
   };
}, []);
```

note: We use apisauce for fetch data;